# What is the functional way to find element by predicate in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

What is the functional way to find element by predicate given that Person is Option in this list.

```
  val idx = list.find(el => {
     el.person.find(_.id == id) match {
       case None => false
       case _ => true
     }
   })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list.find(_.person.exists(_.id == id))
```

But note that this gives you the element itself, not the index.

And since the element is itself wrapped in an `Option` you will want to unwrap it.

```
list.find(_.person.exists(_.id == id)).flatten
```

If you did want the index:

```
list.indexWhere(_.person.exists(_.id == id))
```

Answer (score 1):

[`OptionT`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/optiont.html#optiont) monad transformer from scala cats gives

```
OptionT(l).find(_.id == id)
```

for example

```
import cats.implicits._
import cats.data.OptionT

case class Person(id: Int)

object optionTofListOfOptions extends App {
  val l: List[Option[Person]] = List(Some(Person(42)), Some(Person(11)))
  println(OptionT(l).find(_.id == id))
}
```

outputs

```
Some(Person(42))
```